# Trying to open packages with Anaconda 3

Tags: python

I've installed the FPDF package with the command line, see a confirmation message:

> C:\Users\Usuario>pip install fpdf
> Requirement already satisfied: fpdf in c:\users\usuario\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.7.2)

The problem here is that when I open Anaconda and I try to import the package I get an error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fpdf'

Any idea about how to move all packages to Anadonda in order to avoid this issues?

Comment: Was your anaconda environment activated before you executed `pip install fpdf` ?

Comment: Yes, I've uninstall it and then tried again. I think it's working now!

Comment: Are you in the same environment in which the module was installed?